# Apple Push notification without a SIM card

Tags: apple-push-notifications, sim-card

Just to make sure:
Apple's Push Notiffication Service is supposed to be able to send a push notification to a device that has no SIM card as long as its somehow connected to the internet - right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah it'll work, just device needs to get registered somehow, if your WebService needs such thing !

Telling you Coz, I put a mobile number as a unique ID at server side.

Comment: Yes, the device does register. This is not an issue here. I just wanted to make sure that the fact that there is no SIM is not a reason for apple not to deliver the push notification.